# Combo box to list Macros

Tags: vba, outlook

I want when you hit 'send' you are presented with a form. This I am developing in Outlook 2010.

Is there a way to populate a combo-box with a list of Macros?

```
Public Sub Confidential()
    Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Sensitivity = olConfidential
    Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Save
    Set MsgSub = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set objMail = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Subject = MsgSub.Subject
    MsgSub.Subject = Subject + " - [CONFIDENTIAL]"
    Email = objMail.HTMLBody
    info = " <html> <body> <FONT color=#666666> <font-size: 11px> <p></p> AUTO TEXT: This message has been marked as 'CONFIDENTIAL' please treat it as such </body> </font> </html>"
    objMail.HTMLBody = Email + info
End Sub

Private Sub Sens_DropButtonClick()
    Sens.AddItem "Confidential()"
    Sens.AddItem "Normal()"
End Sub

Public Sub Send_Click()
    Set objMail = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    objMail.Send
End Sub
```

Would I be right in thinking that this is a public sub?

My goal is when you hit the 'send' button a form will appear with a dropdown box, this has 4 options which are the sensitivity options you can use with the emails, except I have created them as macros and added code on them (to add to subject and footer of message) but I wont it so a user is forced to make a selection, hence why I am creating this form instead of having the 4 buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal is when you hit the 'send' button a form will appear with a dropdown box, this has 4 options which are the sensitivity options you can use with the emails, except I have created them as macros and added code on them (to add to subject and footer of message) but I wont it so a user is forced to make a selection, hence why I am creating this form instead of having the 4 buttons. – Rsmithy 36 mins ago

If I understand you correctly, Yes it is possible to do what you want. See this Example

Let's say you have a userform with 4 options A,B,C and D and the userform code is

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "A"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "B"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "C"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "D"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    lstNo = ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Next Paste this in a module

```
Public lstNo As Long
```

and this in the `ThisOutlookSession`

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    UserForm1.Show

    MsgBox "user chose " & lstNo & "from combo"

    Select Case lstNo
    Case -1
        'User didn't select anything in the combo
    Case 0
        'User selected option 1 in the combo
    Case 1
        'User selected option 2 in the combo
    Case 2
        'User selected option 3 in the combo
    Case 3
        'User selected option 4 in the combo
    End Select
End Sub
```

Replace the above comments in the `Select` Statement` with the Macro Names that you want executed depending on the user choice.

**SNAPSHOTS IN ACTION**

[image]

And this is what you get when you select the `Option D (ListIndex 3)`

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

```
Dim email As String, info As String

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    UserForm1.Show

    Select Case lstNo
        Case -1
            'User didn't select anything, default will be used
        Case 0
            With Item
                .Sensitivity = olNormal
                .Save
            End With
        Case 1
            With Item
                .Sensitivity = olPersonal
                .Save
            End With
        Case 2
            With Item
                .Sensitivity = olPrivate
                .Save
            End With
        Case 3
            With Item
                .Sensitivity = olConfidential
                .Subject = .Subject & " - [CONFIDENTIAL]"
                Email = .HTMLBody
                info = " <html> <body> <FONT color=#666666> <font-size: 11px> <p></p> AUTO TEXT: " & _
                "This message has been marked as 'CONFIDENTIAL' please treat it as such </body> </font> </html>"
                .HTMLBody = Email & info
                .Save
            End With
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This is probably obvious, but if you do end up using this method you should probably plan to pass the Item to your macro calls.

Comment: You are right Daniel. The above is just an example that it can be done. :)

Comment: I get a compile error when I click send. 


Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    UserForm1.Show

    MsgBox "user chose " & lstNo & "from combo"

    Select Case lstNo
    Case -1
        'User didn't select anything, default will be used
    Case 0 = MakeThisNormal()
    Case 1 = MakeThisPersonal()
    Case 2 = MakeThisPrivate()
    Case 3 = MakeThisConfidential()
    End Select
End Sub

Comment: although if I have just a textbox (like your example) it does work :)

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Sens.AddItem "Normal"
    Sens.AddItem "Personal"
    Sens.AddItem "Private"
    Sens.AddItem "Confidential"
End Sub


Private Sub Send_Click()
    lstNo = Sens.ListIndex
    Unload Me
End Sub

Comment: ok which line do you get the error in `Application_ItemSend` Do you get the correct message in `"user chose " & lstNo & "from combo"`?

Comment: it doesn't tell me, it highlights that whole line and selects my procure call. "MakeThisNormal()"  When I tested it with the user selected.... (without my procures / Macro) it did work

Comment: Ah! so the error is in `MakeThisNormal` :) Can you share that code as well?

Comment: When I tested so it comes up with a msgbox it worked, but now I'm calling the procure / macros it doesn't. It highlights the 1st line in the 'ThisOutlookSession'

Comment: It seems to not like ANY of my Macros, even though- if used on their own, they work. My Marcos are Public, so I don't see why this isn't working

Comment: Public Sub MakeThisNormal()
Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Sensitivity = olNormal
Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Save
End Sub

Comment: You don't need separate macros for this :) Please see the updated code in my answer (FOLLOWUP). I just tested it and it works :)

Comment: Cheers, that does work, but I have different macros because (for example) my confidential code is:

Comment: Public Sub MakeThisConfidential()
Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Sensitivity = olConfidential
Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Save
Set MsgSub = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Set objMail = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Subject = MsgSub.Subject
MsgSub.Subject = Subject + " - [CONFIDENTIAL]"
email = objMail.HTMLBody
info = " <html> <body> <FONT color=#666666> <font-size: 11px> <p></p> AUTO TEXT: This message has been marked as 'CONFIDENTIAL' please treat it as such </body> </font> </html>"
objMail.HTMLBody = email + info
End Sub

Comment: That is ok :) You can include that code in the above code.. let me show you an example

Comment: Dude cheers! :D that works like a treat. Thanks so much! :D Although 1 thing I am wondering is when you select an option, it doesn't show up- the option still works, but the feild stays blank- is there a way to show it? Is there something like "UserForm_selected"? :)

Comment: WHen you hit send your presented with the dropdown.. when you select it, how can you make it permanently show? Mine stays blank when selected, but it still knows it's selected

Comment: Strange. It shows the selected item when I select an item in the drop down :) Is the combobox big enough? Try and increase the height of the combo...

Comment: Strange :/ Mine just stays blank when an option has been selected... I'll check the options but hight is fine :/

Comment: Just for testing purpose... can you make it realllllly big :D Also check the font property of the combo.

Comment: Font Tahoma 8. Height 181.5   ....Still no luck.... Although, I do get the blinking "|" where it should be

Comment: Font Color, I hope is not set to white?

Comment: I only have "Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()"  and nothing for click?

Comment: you should have the commandbutton click code as I showed int he snapshot above... BRB Stepping out for 20 mins. Also delete the combo and create it again. see what happens...

Comment: Resolved... just recreated it :D ...thanks for your help :) Enjoy the rest of your day!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to populate a combo-box with a list of Macros?

Not in Outlook, I'm afraid. Programmatic access to the VBA IDE isn't supported in Outlook due to the possibility of spreading viruses or conducting malicious activity via email.

See [VBA Extensibility in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11355245/190829) for reference.

The closest you can come is by programmatically displaying the "Run Macro" dialog, like this:

`ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.FindControl(,186).Execute`

However I'm not sure if this is available in Outlook 2010.

But showing a dialog box can't possibly be your goal. Maybe if you explain what your goal is, someone can suggest a better way of reaching it that doesn't require populating a combo box with a list of macro names.

Comment: My goal is when you hit the 'send' button a form will appear with a dropdown box, this has 4 options which are the sensitivity options you can use with the emails, except I have created them as macros and added code on them (to add to subject and footer of message) but I wont it so a user is forced to make a selection, hence why I am creating this form instead of having the 4 buttons.

Comment: @Rsmithy You should have put this into your (original) question.