# updating userform in outlook using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I have written some vba (userforms mostly) to help my colleges with various task in Outlook, every time I write some extra code I have go to twenty desk to perform a manual update because outlook can't access the vba model.

[VBA Extensibility in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355245/vba-extensibility-in-outlook)

is there a way to automate this update? using sendkeys was suggested but this is not actualy an update, you would still have to delete the old file manualy. Some of my colleges can't handle that. :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Extensibility in Outlook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355245/vba-extensibility-in-outlook) ... why post a question that you **already** know is a direct duplicate of the question you linked to in your question?

Comment: Because the question is not whether it is accessible but if anyone has found a way around it other than using sendkeys.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-user solutions should really be designed as a COM Add-in. VBA macros in Outlook were never intended to be deployed and are meant for personal use only. However, there are some deployment methods available - see here, but use at your own risk: http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=28